# Why can't Pakyow find 'soft_copy' method in new route?

Tags: pakyow

I need help with a `[500] undefined method 'soft_copy' for nil:NilClass` error when calling `action :list do` for a new view. The only line in the route is `view.scope(:user).apply(User.all)` and `puts User.all` returns an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to apply (or bind) to a scope that doesn't exist in your view. Verify that a `user` scope exists in the `users` view path.